# ExpandableListView onExpand always scroll expanded group to top

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i`m looking for way to position expandableListView group on top, when expanded.
I tried onGroupExpand, or in performItemClick of ExpandableListView.

setSelectedPositionFromTop(int, int), partialy works, but if it starts in a time when system starts it's own scroll, than list is overscrolled, and group is out of screen.

Sorry for messy description, but it's hard to say without showing exactly what i need.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I have solution to this problem. It's not gentle one, but it works quite fine.
Expandable listView messures is it should move by child number. It seems, that system thinks that child is same height as parent(group), so if you put different size child it will cause problems with auto scrolling list.

My solution was to trick list to think that it has more children.
If my child is twice as big as group, i just return information that group has 2 children. Now, since it is data constructed list, i make check on my data, is there a data for 2 childs, or only 1, if i don't have data for second child, i know that i can put 0 height view as second child.

It worked fine when i had to make List with small group, and than with 1 big child.

Since there was no answer to my question, i post this one, it may help someone.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, it wont change that none of you could help, and solution is still working as intended.

Comment: Try my new solution above.

Comment: Thats enough SO for the day

Answer (score 5):

Change transcriptmode to disabled.

```
android:transcriptmode="disabled"
```

in expandable list layout.

Comment: You can just omit this attribute. It worked for me without transcriptmode.

Comment: @DennySharma you can omit this atribute because disabled mode is default mode. This is from documentation:
"Disables transcript mode. This is the default value."
Please see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode

Comment: use this property in xml : android:transcriptMode="disabled" this property is available @DennySharma

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your adapter:

```
public void onGroupExpanded(final int groupPosition) {
     super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);

     listView.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setSelection(groupPosition) in onGroupExpand(int groupPosition).

Comment: It works only in some cases, than if let's say my group is at the bottom, and it will in the same moment setSelection, and than scroll to reveal children, than group is overscrolled out of screen.

Comment: @Drake29a hi your issue is solved are not?In my case also group is overscrolled out of screen?

Comment: It was solved by my answer, which is accepted one. It was nasty trick, but had no other solution. I can't check other solutions now, since I have no access to that old code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many solutions but the below code works for me.Hope this code will be helpful for some one.Implements the OnGroupExpandListener with in onGroupExpand
use the below code

```
public void onGroupExpand(final int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpand(groupPosition);

    expandableListView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            expandableListView.setSelection(groupPosition);
            if(expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition)!=null)
            expandableListView.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition),
                    new Rect(0, 0, expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition).getRight(), expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition).getHeight()), false);
        }
    });
}
```